# DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.Why?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am using Matlab to calculate a double integral. The error is:

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 
Error using mupadmex
    Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double
    array. If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Error in sym/double (line 827)
    Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error in MeEqu7 (line 20)
     out2 =out2 (int(int(yi,u1,0,u2),u2, 0 ,1000))
```

and my code is as follows:

```
clear all; 

a=4; 
la1=1/(pi*500^2); la2= la1*5;
p1=25; p2=p1/25;
sgma2=10^(-11);
index=1;
g=2./a;

syms r u1 u2  u3 aa
powe= 0;
seta= 10^powe;


xNor =  (u2./u1).^(-1./g) + 1  ;
aa= -u2.^(-1./g) .*seta.*( pi.*(la1.*p1.^(g) + la2.*p2.^(g)) ).^(1./g)  ;


yi =  exp(aa./xNor - u2 );
out2 = double (int(int(yi,u1,0,u2),u2, 0 ,1000))
```

Thanks alot for your help!!
I also tried vpa. but the out2 is not a number. Actually, I am expecting the out2 is a number, sothat I can use this number to plot a figure.
I did some search here. but their case is not helpful for my case. Could you take a deeper look?

Comment: Try `vpa` instead of `double`. There are many "duplicate" questions that likely suggest this and the error message does too. Have you tried it? If it works, you can convert that output to floating-point using `double`.

Comment: @horchler not to mention the error message itself.

Comment: @horchler Hey, Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I do search those topic, but it is not helpful for my case. I just tried to use vpa, and it output is numeric::int(exp(- u2 - 1934281311383407/(1208925819614629174706176*u2^2*(u1^2/u2^2 + 1))), u1 == 0..u2).   Actually, I expect some numbers, I want to use the out2 to plot a figure.  Could you take a deeper look for me?  Thank you very much.

Comment: My guess is that MuPAD tries to first integrate symbolically and then evaluate the result, and the symbolic integration fails. If you want a numeric result, try numeric integration?

Comment: Thanks guys. I think someting wrong with the first int. the output of first int is still function of u2.  I need to check more on that.